# MySQL Deadlock Batch Size

Tags: mysql, deadlock

I am writing data to MySQL. There can be a lot of data (30M rows). The default batch size is 1,000 and I'm writing in parallel, so we could have 8 processes, each writing 1,000 records to the DB at any given time,

I run into deadlock issues quite frequently - I'm not entirely sure why, as I am inserting rows, so we should not have a situation where they're accessing the same row.

I have tried to lower the batch size to 500, but the issue still persists.

Do you have any advice please?

Thanks

Comment: If the table you are writing to supports transactions simply start a transaction, do all of the inserts then commit the transaction.

Comment: What is your table definition? Do it have both a PRIMARY KEY and a secondary UNIQUE KEY?

Comment: just one composite primary key (4 columns)

Comment: What transaction isolation level do you use? The default REPEATABLE-READ, or can you try READ-COMMITTED?

Comment: deadlocks on these inserts, or deadlocks on other activity?  have you tried not doing it in parallel?  do show us your code, *how* you are writing the data could be a factor.  and please do show (as text, not an image) output of `show create table yourtablename` that will tell us many valuable things.

Comment: Have you changed the server configuration defaults? The out of the box experience is *terrible*. You absolutely need to tune InnoDB.